# Probability of drawing balls from a jar

Tags: probability

> A jar contains 7 balls, 3 red, 4 white. 2 balls are drawn without replacement, what is the probability of the first ball was white given the second is white?

So I have conditional probability $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

I get probability the second ball is white as the the probability of having red then white or the probability of white then white. As $\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{7}$ and $\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{3}{6}=\frac{2}{7}$, then probability the second is white is $\frac{2}{7}+\frac{2}{7}=\frac{4}{7}$

But I don't know how to use the formula.

Comment: Hint for your question:  so you've got $P(B)$.  Now all you need is $P(A\cap B)$.  Actually, you have that one as well.

Comment: As @lulu said, you've got all the pieces written down already.  Can you pinpoint your difficulty using the formula?

Comment: I don't understand how to get $P(A\cap B)$ since $P(B)$ depends on $P(A)$ so I can't just multiply them together.

Comment: As an aside, in any jar with any number of red and white balls, taking balls at random with *or* without replacement, for any $k$ the probability that the $k$'th is white is going to be the same as the probability that the first is white.  Further, the probability that the $n$'th is white given that the $k$'th is white is the same as the probability the second is white given that the first is white.

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ is the probability that ball $1$ is white (event $A$) and ball $2$ is white (event $B$).  You've already calculated that correctly, without, as you say, multiplying the probabilities together, which would indeed be wrong.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why I can do that since $P(B)$ depends on $P(A)$. So I shouldnt be able to multiply them together to get $P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Nobody is telling you to multiply $P(A)$ by $P(B).$ You have written a number of calculations already, all of which are correct. Now look where you wrote "the probability of white then white." You have answered your own question, apparently without realizing it.

Comment: While you could use Bayes' theorem, it is unnecessarily complicated.  Instead, consider what is the probability that the second ball is white given that the first ball is white?  Is that problem any different in any substantial way?  But, I bet you know how to answer the it when we have flipped things around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion over what an event is and how they are related, so let me try to clarify that in a few different ways.

In this particular problem, we have that:

Event $A$: drawing the first ball, it is white

Event $B$: drawing the second ball, it is white

Picture each event as an action with a result, and this is how we can assign probabilities to them. We say that these two particular probabilities are *dependent* if the probability of $B$ happening can change depending on whether or not $A$ happens, and vice-versa.

This, however, is **not** the same as saying $P(B)$ depends on $P(A)$. The two values $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are fixed because they are referring to the *total* probability, beginning from before any ball is drawn.

Try to picture the events and possible ball draws in the following Venn diagram:

[image: venn]

We can let the left circle represent $A$ and the right circle represent $B$. The middle represents $A \cap B$, or drawing two white balls. The outside of the Venn diagram represents $\neg A \cap \neg B$, where we draw two red balls.

$P(A)$ is the entirely of the set of the left circle divided by all possible outcomes, including the ones outside the Venn diagram ($\neg A \cap \neg B$). $P(A \mid B)$ means we don't even look outside the domain of the set $B$. Within only the right circle, what is the set of $A$ (in this case, the intersection) divided by the set of $B$?

Drawing red ($\neg A$) then drawing white ($B$) gives us the region outside the left circle but inside the right circle. Drawing white ($A$) then white ($B$) gives us the region inside both circles. When you add these regions, you get the probability of the entire right circle, $P(B)$.

---

**Additional notes and shortcuts for solving this problem:**

The problem is symmetrical between the first and second draws of the balls. This is because just as we can draw ball $1$ and then ball $2$, we can also draw ball $2$ and then ball $1$. Therefore, $P(A \mid B) = P(B \mid A)$. Thus, $P(A \mid B)$ is simply the probability of drawing a single white ball after one white ball is removed, $\frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Im wondering though why Bayes Theorem doesn't seem to work here? If $P(A)=\frac{4}{7}$ and $P(B)=\frac{3}{6}$ I would then take $P(A\mid B)=\frac{\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{3}{6}}{\frac{3}{6}}=\frac{4}{7}$.

Comment: $P(A) = P(B)$ because of the symmetry I mentioned earlier. You already found $P(B)$ in your opening post. $P(A \mid B) = \frac{3}{6} \neq P(B)$.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why I can't use bayes theorem here. Because I don't feel like I'll ever notice symmetry instead of just figuring out the probabilities individually

Comment: You CAN use Bayes Theorem. You just used it incorrectly because you didn't clearly understand and label the terms, such as $P(B)$ and $P(A \mid B)$. If you used Bayes Theorem correctly, you would get the right answer. The symmetry bit is just extra, you don't need to understand it to get Bayes Theorem.